# How to open projects as tabs on macOS in Goland IDE

Tags: intellij-idea, goland

can not open projects in tabs
Can anyone please let me know how to open multiple projects as tabs in Goland
[wanted tabs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJWeJ.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i found new hidden option to merge all opend window in tabs

first follow this answer from  [s0xzwasd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13576700/s0xzwasd)

> s0xzwasd
>
> - Set Prefer tabs in macOS Preferences | General to Always or In
>   full-screen.
> - Open a new project in the IDE, select New Window in Open
>   Project pop-up or configure it via Preferences | Appearance & Behavior
>   | System Settings | Open project in.

and

- **Window**
- choose **Merge all project windows**
  [preview image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NslNV.png)

Answer (score 3):

- Set *Prefer tabs* in *macOS Preferences | General* to *Always* or *In full-screen*.
- Open a new project in the IDE, select *New Window* in *Open Project* pop-up or configure it via *Preferences | Appearance & Behavior | System Settings | Open project in*.

Answer (score 1):

workaround ::

- Launch GoLand
- Open Project1: auto full screen
- Open Project2: auto full screen in another window
- Quit GoLand at dock
- Relaunch GoLand: Project1&2 are auto open and group as tabs in same window